# Querying entities from DocumentDB returns incomplete elements

Tags: c#, .net, azure-cosmosdb

I'm pretty new to Microsoft DocumentDB and I need to run some queries to it.

I'm storing this type of objects in a collection:

```
public class GroupedSales
{
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public long Site { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public int Hour { get; set; }
        public int Week { get; set; }
        public int GradeNumber { get; set; }
        public int Transactions { get; set; }
        public double TotalVolume { get; set; }
        public double TotalMoney { get; set; }
}
```

And retrieving elements running a method which receives the following filters encapsulated in a class:

```
public enum GroupingBy
{
        Hour,
        Day,
        Week,
        Month
};

public class SaleQueryFilter
{
        public List<int> Grades { get; set; }
        public List<long> Sites { get; set; }
        public GroupingBy GroupingBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime From { get; set; }
        public DateTime To { get; set; }
}
```

Finally, the query is the following:

```
private List<GroupedSales> GetRawData(SaleQueryFilter filter)
{
    return Client.CreateDocumentQuery<GroupedSales>(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseId, DocumentCollectionId))
                 .Where(x => x.Date >= filter.From.Date
                             && x.Date <= filter.To.Date
                             && filter.Sites.Contains(x.Site)
                             && filter.Grades.Contains(x.GradeNumber)).ToList();
}
```

The thing is that if I do not include the attribute `Week` inside the `Where` clause, then this attribute is not being populated with the value stored in the document.

I've been struggling with this issue for the last two days and could not find any answer. Could you give me some help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Remember, DocumentDB has no date/time type. You are doing a range filter on dates. How are the dates stored in the database as an epoch integer? as an ISO-8601 canonical string in zulu time? Those would work as long as you had a range index on that field. But if it's storing it as a localized string or even if it's an ISO-8601 string with a timezone offset, you might get unexpected results.

So, my best guess is that it's either an index issue or how you are storing dates.

Comment: I assumed that you could leverage [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to capture the request when you invoking `CreateDocumentQuery`. You could find the query string looks like `{"query":"SELECT * FROM root WHERE ((((root[\"Date\"] >= \"2017-01-11T00:00:00+08:00\") AND (root[\"Date\"] <= \"2017-01-12T00:00:00+08:00\")) AND (root[\"Site\"] IN (1, 2))) AND (root[\"GradeNumber\"] IN (1, 2))) "}`, you could copy the query into "Query Explorer" on Azure Portal and run it to see the results.If possible,please attach some screenshot when you include/exclude attribute Week inside Where clause.

Comment: Thank both for the comments, if I run the query without any filters I experience the same issue so I don´t think it´s something related to the dates.

Comment: Have you tried to follow my suggestion and run the equivalent SQL query for DocumentDB  via [Query Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-query-collections-query-explorer)? Could you retrieve the results as expected?

Comment: Hi Bruce, Finally I could retrieve the results as expected. Don't know if it was a problem os the document collection or the database but a created a  database and collection from scratch and it worked like a charm. 
Maybe the problem with the Week attribute was that this attribute was added to the class after the document collection was created and then I ran some process to populate it.